# To Split into fixed sequences and leave extra out

Tags: shell, unix, split

I would like to limit all files to be of the same fixed length but the last item can be any variable size but not more than 557.
This means that the file amount can be more than determined by the flag `-n` of the command `split`.

### Code 1 (ok)

```
$ seq -w 1 1671 > /tmp/k && gsplit -n15 /tmp/k && wc -c xaa && wc -c xao
557 xaa
557 xao
```

where *xaa* is the first file of the sequence, while *xao* the last one.
I increase the sequence by one unit but it causes 5 unit increase (557->562) in the last file *xao* which I do not understand:

```
$ seq -w 1 1672 > /tmp/k && gsplit -n15 /tmp/k && wc -c xaa && wc -c xao
557 xaa
562 xao
```

Why does the increase of one-unit in sequence increase the last item (xao) by 5 units?

### Code 2

```
$ seq -w 1 1671 | gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' > /tmp/k && gsplit -n15 /tmp/k&& wc -c xaa && wc -c xao
445 xaa
455 xao
$ seq -w 1 1672 | gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' > /tmp/k && gsplit -n15 /tmp/k&& wc -c xaa && wc -c xao
445 xaa
459 xao
```

so increasing the whole length by one sequence (4 characters) leads to 4 character increase (455 -> 459), in contrast to the first code where increase is 5 characters.

### Code 3

Let's now keep each unit of sequence fixed to 4 characters by `seq -w 0 0.0001 1 | gsed 's/\.//g'`:

```
$ seq -w 0 0.0001 1 | gsed 's/\.//g' |  gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' > /tmp/k && gsplit -n15 /tmp/k&& wc -c xaa && wc -c xao
3333 xaa
3344 xao
$ seq -w 0 0.0001 1.0001 | gsed 's/\.//g' |  gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' > /tmp/k && gsplit -n15 /tmp/k&& wc -c xaa && wc -c xao
3334 xaa
3335 xao
```

so increasing the sequence by one characters increases *xaa* by unit but decreases *xao* by 9 units. 
This behavior is what I do not keep so logical.

How can you limit the sequence length first, for instance to be fixed at 557 and later determine the amount of files of successful files?

Comment: Beware: this is becoming a 'chameleon question' — that's not popular.  Please ask the whole question up front.  Do not ask your question incrementally.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, you are right! I had to explain better what I am looking for here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31238142/54964 I want to overload the the flag `-n` to keep the distribution of loading the sequences more smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Original answer — for Code 1

Because `seq -w 1 1671` generates 5 characters per number — 4 digits and 1 newline.  So adding one number to the output adds 5 bytes to the output.

#### Extra answer — for Code 2

You've asked GNU `split` (aka `gsplit`) to split the file input into 15 chunks.  It does its best to even the values out.  But there's a limit to what it can do when the total number of bytes is not a multiple of 15.  There are options to control what happens.

However, in the basic form, the `-n 15` option means that the first 14 output files each get 445 characters, and the last gets 455 because there are 6685 = 445 * 15 + 10 characters in the output file.  When you add another 4 characters to the file (because you delete the newlines), then the last file gets an additional 4 characters (because 6689 = 445 * 15 + 14).

#### Extra answer — for Code 3

First of all, the output from `seq -w 0 0.0001 1` looks like:

```
0.0000
0.0001
0.0002
…
0.9998
0.9999
1.0000
```

So after the output is edited with the first `sed`, the numbers from 00000 to 10000 are present, one per line, with 6 characters per line (including the newline).  The second `sed` eliminates the newlines, again.

There are 50006 bytes in `/tmp/k` on one line. That's equal to 15 * 3333 + 11, hence the first output.  The second variant has 50011 bytes in `/tmp/k`, which is 15 * 3334 + 1.  Hence the difference of only one.

Comment: I had to add 2 more examples to illustrate the case better. In code 1 - 5 character increase, in code 2 - 4 character increase. In code 3, the unit of sequence is kept fixed but moving load from right-hand side to to left. This how this distribution of these loads are done are unknown to me.

Comment: I'm not clear from reading the manual whether you can do what you want.  I think you're asking that if there are 11 bytes more than a multiple of 15, you want one of the extra bytes to be added to each of the first 11 files, rather than have them all added to the last.  I don't see a mechanism for achieving that.

Comment: I think there has to be other mechanism to control this better: to be able to limit the amount of sequences per file such that the command gives an error if the condition is broken. I think one mechanism to achieve this is to control `-n` as a group of values.

Comment: If you establish the size, you can almost use `gsplit -b 3334 /tmp/k`, but that gives you 14 files all containing 3334 bytes and one containing 3330 bytes (for the 50006 byte version of `/tmp/k`).  That too isn't quite what you want.  Using `gsplit -b 3333 /tmp/k` gave 16 files, 15 of length 3333 bytes and one of length 11.  That seems to be different from what you're after.

Comment: My gut feel is you're going to have to add a new option, maybe `-s` (`--smooth`), to GNU `split` to provide the 'as even as possible, no more than one byte difference between the sizes of the output files'.  I'm not sure that many people will need it, but it may have its uses to some people.  (I'd suggest `-e` or `--even` but `-e` is already in use, short for `--elide-empty-files`.)

Comment: Great! The option `-e` improves the situation.

Comment: You do realize that I'm suggesting modifying the source code.  The option you want is not available as standard.

Comment: Yes, I realize. I am thinking if it could be realized by combining different flags and adding some command. The benefit of the flag `-e` comes when you can force files to be of some interval length.