# To Split into fixed sequences smoothly by group values of flags

Tags: algorithm, shell, unix, data-structures, split

I want to split as even as possible, no more than one byte difference between the sizes of the output files by altering the amount files but having some minimum number and maximum number of files. 
The first thread of this discussion about load behavior of sequences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31231098/54964) where I provided too few cases to explain the sequence behavior but where the increment leads to 5 character increase in the last sequence. 
Different conditions of flags can be used.

### Data-structure

This smoothing cannot be accomplished with only well defined algorithm. 
I just have an intuition that a partial index could work because there are always just a small subset which has data and the smoothing occurs dynamically through the entries of the directory. 
The solution may involve some well chosen data-structure with some algorithm.

### Pseudocode for algorithm

I would like to affect the loading behavior of the characters into the resulted files which occurs at the moment rather unlogically and not smoothly.

```
$ seq -w 0 0.0001 1                                \
| gsed 's/\.//g'                                   \
| gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' > /tmp/k                \
&& gsplit -n{a,b} -e -b{k,n,m} /tmp/k              \
&& wc -c 1stFile && wc -c lastFile
```

where

- parts of the command `gsplit -n{a,b} -b{k,n,m}` is just pseudocommand
- flags `n` and `b` can be used
- `-e` elides empty files from the output but it is not enough alone to force the output to be in some interval
- The flag `-n` with single value leads to fixed amount of files but can be narrowed to minimum by `-e` so processing each unit of group separately is the possible situation here.
- The definiteness of the flag `-n`, when only a single value, leads to strange loading behavior of sequences into files.

How can you control better the loading of new sequences into new files without rapid peaks in some files?

Comment: As @user464502 excellent answer points out, you will have 0 or more solutions to your constraint problem of two variables (file size and number of files).  You can use its output to guide splitting, probably with `csplit`.  What I don't understand is *why* you want this. I honestly feel this question, as stated, is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a shell script that will figure out allowable combinations
of file sizes and quantities given various parameters.  It will exit
successfully if any combinations are found, and exits failure if
no possible combinations are found for the given inputs.  Note that
not all possible combinations of parameters have a solution.
If it is necessary that a solution be provided, the number of allowed
files can be increased or decreased.  The trivial cases of two
files or a number of files equal to the number of bytes are always
solvable.

```
#!/bin/sh

# N is the bytes total.
# L is the lowest number of files allowable.
# H is the highest number of files allowable.
# F is the actual number of files used
# B is the minimum bytes per file
# R is the remaining bytes if all files are of size B
# K is the maximum number of files allowed to be one byte larger than the
# minimum, K < F
# 
# So, you need to determine if there is some L <= F <= H such that R <= K.
# 
# For a given candidate F:
# B = floor(N / F)
# R = N % B
# if R <= K then the candidate F is allowable, F files will be used,
# R of them will be of size B+1 and F-R of them will be of size B.

# usage: <program> <bytes> <min files> <max files> [max larger files]
# copyright disclaimed, this program is in the public domain

N=$1
L=$2
H=$3
K=${4:-1} # default to one file allowed to be larger

status=1
echo checking number of files F: $L '<= F <=' $H, at most $K one byte larger
for F in $(seq $L $H); do
        B=$(($N / $F))
        R=$(($N % $B))
        if [ $R -le $K ]; then
                if [ $R -eq 0 ]; then
                echo Usable: $F files, size $B
                else
                echo Usable: $F files, $(($F - $R)) size $B, $R size $(($B+1))
                fi
                status=0;
        fi
done
exit $status
```

Some examples:

A largish prime number of bytes:

```
% sh trysplit 16769023 3 100; echo $?
checking number of files F: 3 <= F <= 100, at most 1 files one byte larger
Usable: 3 files, 2 size 5589674, 1 size 5589675
Usable: 6 files, 5 size 2794837, 1 size 2794838
Usable: 61 files, 60 size 274902, 1 size 274903
0
%
```

Well, it has some solutions, but ugh.

How about a luckier number:

```
% sh trysplit 16769024 3 100; echo $?
checking number of files F: 3 <= F <= 100, at most 1 files one byte larger
Usable: 4 files, size 4192256
Usable: 8 files, size 2096128
Usable: 16 files, size 1048064
Usable: 23 files, size 729088
Usable: 32 files, size 524032
Usable: 46 files, size 364544
Usable: 64 files, size 262016
Usable: 89 files, size 188416
Usable: 92 files, size 182272
0
%
```

One byte larger and you've got lots of choices.

What if we allow more than one file to be larger:

```
% sh trysplit 16769023 3 100 2; echo $?
checking number of files F: 3 <= F <= 100, at most 2 files one byte larger
Usable: 3 files, 2 size 5589674, 1 size 5589675
Usable: 6 files, 5 size 2794837, 1 size 2794838
Usable: 17 files, 15 size 986413, 2 size 986414
Usable: 61 files, 60 size 274902, 1 size 274903
0
%
```

What if any of them can be larger?  I think in this case, but
haven't proved, that you can use any number of files you want,
it will just affect the distribution of how many are one byte
larger.  You can use the script to see if the exact number of
files you want works by setting the minimum and maximum files
the same and the allowed to be different to one less than that.

This can be adapted to just print out the parameters you are interested
in so you can use it to populate a shell variable that can then
be used to construct the appropriate split command.

Comment: Have you studied how the script distributes the files? Where does it put those files with one byte larger size? Randomly to the file sequence or by some logic?

Comment: It doesn't distribute the files at all, it just computes solutions to the problem constraints.  If you want an actual program you can find one at https://pd.if.org/git/scripts/